# XEN or KVM: which provides more reliable support for FreeBSD/OpenBSD guests?

Tags: freebsd, virtual-machine, kvm, openbsd, xen

Which hypervisor provides more reliable support for the most popular two BSDs?

I read an article that Linode moved to KVM from XEN, and found a page named 'guest support status' on linux-kvm.org, but I can't find much recent info on BSD support in XEN.

Comment: I've had great luck with some flavors of FreeBSD, particularly PC-BSD, on qemu-kvm.  No experience with xen or OpenBSD.

Answer (score 3):

## Xen:

- Since 5.9 OpenBSD included [PVHVM drivers](https://www.openbsd.org/papers/asiabsdcon2016-xen-paper.pdf) enabled by default. [This commit](http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=145271648304212&w=2) done by `mikeb` confirms. This was written from scratch, and there is even a c[omparison with the FreeBSD code](https://www.openbsd.org/papers/bsdcan2016-xen.pdf) and how OpenBSD drivers are simpler and yet powerfull. The [`xen`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.9/xen.4) driver probes for paravirtualized devices such as disk and network interfaces and performs HVM domU guest initialization, abstraction for virtual Xen interrupts and access to the XenStore configuration storage.
- FreeBSD works the same way with [PVHVM drivers](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/Xen). It's not full PV, but it benefits from drivers with PV features. The difference here is that with some tweaking, you can [run FreeBSD as Dom0](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Dom0#Shortcomings)

**Related links:**

- [libvirt/libxl on FreeBSD](http://empt1e.blogspot.com.br/2015/06/libvirtlibxl-on-freebsd.html)

## KVM:

- Since 5.3, OpenBSD supports [`virtio`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man4/virtio.4) with the 0.95 spec with the following drivers being commited some releases later: `vio(4)` - network device, `vioblk(4)` - disk, `viomb(4)` - memory ballooning driver, `viornd(4)` - random number device, `vioscsi(4)` - SCSI adapter; Note that other virtualization technologies support `virtio`(VirtualBox, Xen, bhyve). This interface was ported from NetBSD drivers.
- The same way, FreeBSD implements [`virtio`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=virtio&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) driver however, you need to compile them if you are running a version older than 10.0(the manpage seems to be outdated, as for today modules are included on `GENERIC`). You should have good performance the same way as `OpenBSD` running on KVM, since both OS's have the PVH drivers for i/o, block, ethernet, scsi and balooning.

**tl,dr**: Both virtualization solutions will give you HVM with PVH drivers for those guests. Performance should be the same or near.

Answer (score 2):

OpenBSD works better on KVM. OpenBSD only supports Xen HVM, not PVM.

I can't help you with FreeBSD.